# Common Controls 6.0 in Windows 2000?

Tags: windows, deployment, mfc, common-controls

I'm wanting to use Grouping in CListCtrls, which seems to have been introduced in Common Controls 6. CC6 only came out with XP, so we have a problem with Windows 2000 and earlier. Deploying a new version of Comctl32.dll would seem to be the solution - however, our software has the requirement of being a standalone executable.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunate information from Microsoft:

> Unlike earlier versions of
>   ComCtl32.dll, version 6 is not
>   redistributable. The only way you can
>   use version 6 of the dynamic-link
>   library (DLL) is to use an operating
>   system that contains it.

Found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997646.aspx